# ORACLE APEX 5 Hide datepicker icon tabular form

Tags: jquery, oracle, oracle-apex, tabular-form, oracle-apex-5

I need to hide the date picker icon from the tabular form, and to show the calendar on click as is in the Forms.
Thanks.

[image: Tabular Form]

Comment: Please provide us with some code of what you have, and ideally what you have tried.

Comment: There is no code, but I will edit my answar and add a photo for what I need.

Comment: We need some code to help you I'm afraid. We're not contractors.

Comment: Dude, I'm sure that I need JQuery or JavaScript code to solve my problem. But I'm not familiar with these languages. so I prefer to let it empty than posting some Idiot Codes and make fun of myself.

Comment: can i ask if you have more than 1 datepicker in your page or tabular form.

Comment: There is 2 datepickers, but I deleted END_DATE because the user didn't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only have **ONE** datepicker inside the tabular form or your page. Go to the main page then on the **EXECUTE WHEN PAGE LOADS** section, copy and paste this:

```
$(".a-Button.a-Button--popupLOV, .u-TF-item--datepicker + .a-Button--calendar").css("visibility", "hidden");

$("input[name="+'f07'+"]").click(function(){
$(".a-Button.a-Button--popupLOV, .u-TF-item--datepicker + .a-Button--calendar").css("visibility", "visible");
})
```

Change `f07` to the name of your datepicker. To get the name, right click the datepicker field then click `INSPECT ELEMENT` and then copy the name youll find on the higlighted area on HTML block.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **settings** in page item and choose **"onFocus"** on **show** 
[image]